# Произвести или провести оплату по счету

Tags: грамотная-речь

Уточните, пожалуйста, как будет верно: "Произвести оплату по счету" или "Провести оплату по счету"?
**UPD:** Например, "Высылаю Вам счет на рассмотрение, когда Вы планируется произвести (провести) оплату по данному счету?" или "Счет на оплату услуг во вложении, просьба произвести (провести) оплату по счету до дд.мм.гг"

Comment: Мало информации. Можете добавить несколько примеров, с контекстом (как на самом деле говорит, пишет ваш главный бухгалтер)?

Comment: @stopkran, добавила несколько примеров.

Comment: В таком контексте - только "произвести", без вариантов.

Comment: Да, присоединяюсь. Произвести.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оплату в бытовом смысле не проводят, а производят, осуществляют."Произвести оплату"-фразеологизм со знач. "оплатить".

Провести в бухг. означает "сделать запись".
Для того чтобы внести сумму (информацию) по любому счету учета в систему бухгалтерского учета, необходимо создать запись (проводку по счетам).

Т.е. если Вы бухгалтер и вам необходимо оформить оплату,то Вы пишете "провести сумму по счёту №...", если Вам нужно заплатить сумму, Вы говорите "произвести оплату по счету".

Comment: Согласна с Вами.

Comment: Я вижу, мы во многом единомышленники, спасибо, честно говоря, на многих сайтах русского языка начинают "третировать", цепляются к словам, я не люблю склок, сразу ухожу, мне никакое лидерство нигде не нужно, просто хочется помочь людям разобраться с трудными вопросами в нашем многострадальном сложном языке.

Comment: У нас это тоже бывает (цепляние к словам). Стараюсь не отвечать.

Comment: @Ларf, @Людмила, спасибо Вам большое за помощь! Людмила, когда начали говорить о применении данного термина в бухгалтерии, сразу вспомнился бухгалтерский термин - "проводки", видимо, отсюда и "провести".

Comment: > сразу вспомнился бухгалтерский термин - "проводки", видимо, отсюда и "провести".  
  
Это совсем другое. И вообще не стоит мешать сюда бухгалтерский слэнг. Я опускаю формулировкой (с тем что это просто "запись"согласен от силы на треть), но в бухгалтерском значении "провести оплату по счету" если и возможно, то в совершенно специфическом значении. даже если беседую два бухгалтера, то "провести оплату" скорее всего будет означать "организовать и выполнить мероприятие по оплате".

Comment: >У нас это тоже бывает (цепляние к словам). Стараюсь не отвечать.  
  
И очень зря, говорил уже это Вам. У Вас бывает очень полезная информация и ценное  мнение.  Если кто-то с Вами не согласен или переспрашивает - это еще не значит, что Вас умышленно оскорбляют. Напротив, обычно именно такие "неприкасаемые" формчани становятся мишенью для троллей. По мне - так при наличии технической возможности имеет смысл отвечать на любые, сколько-нибудь содержательные вопросы, особенно непосредственно ко мне обращенные 

Не красен форум единомышленниками. Он богат *разномышленниками*.

Comment: Почему ж другое? Посмотрите у Ожегова.Провести, знач.7-спец. оформить. Моя мама была бухгалтером, я к этим терминам привыкла.К тому же сейчас после Вашего комментария прошлась по сайтам.Вопрос:"Можно ли эти платежи провести по бухгалтерии и вернуть деньги директору, и если да, то какие следует сделать проводки и оформить дополнительные документы?" Ответ:"Можете через авансовые отчеты провести", т.е. оформить, записать, сделать проводку.

Comment: @tmp, (я не цепляюсь к словам), мне кажется, что "провести оплату" всё-таки в бухгалтерии не говорят. *Проводят*, скорее, документы, платежи...

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, что в зависимости от ситуации, возможны оба варианта. Мне прислали счет. Я должна произвести оплату счета, т.е. оплатить данный счет. А вот в банке работники, выполняя операции, наверное, проводят оплату по счету, т.е. направляют на нужный счет.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, здесь нельзя гадать. "Провести" - специфический бухгалтерский термин; какими конструкциями он может управлять, что и как можно "проводить", думаю, может сказать только профессионал-бухгалтер (не обязательно в банке). Например, типичная конструкция (на слуху): "провести задним числом" - что? какие документы?

Так же, собственно, и с выражением "произвести оплату". Очевидным кажется, что можно *оплатить счёт*, *произвести оплату счёта*. Но, вероятно, в бухгалтерии можно и *произвести оплату ПО счёту* (такое выражение не будет ошибкой).

Comment: @stopkran, спасибо! Вы затронули даже больше: "оплата счета" и "оплата по счету", никогда раньше не задумывалась, всегда говорила "оплата по счету", действительно, правильней будет - "произвести оплату счета". Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не надо на бухгалтерию ссылаться. Дело не в управлении, "провести" в бухгалтерии - нечто совершенно не совпадающее с "произвести" (если интересно - смотрите на термин "проводка бухгалтерская" и подобное). Но если говорить о бытовом языке, то это надо понимать примерно так:

"Провести" - организовать, осуществить руководство.
"Произвести" - выполнить, реализовать.

Смотрите сами, что Вам ближе. По мне так - произвести.

Comment: @tmp, согласна, ближе - "произвести", спасибо!